# Prevent overlapping nodes with arbor.js

Tags: visualization, arbor.js

I am trying to do an animation using arbor.js. I want to display about 50 to 100 weighted nodes, where the weight defines the size of the node. I was able to display all the nodes but the heavier nodes concentrate in the center and overlap each other. There is a lot of empty space in the canvas that can be used to spread out the nodes.

Is there a setting I can use to not have the nodes overlap?

Answer (score 1):

When creating your particle system use more repulsion, ie. 10000 instead of the default 1000:

`arbor.ParticleSystem(10000);`

This will not prevent overlapping, but may fix your display problem.